# AttributeError: module 'scipy.ndimage' has no attribute 'interpolation' Tensorflow CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scipy, conv-neural-network

This is a part of my code, before data augmentation, `model.fit` was working, however after augmentation of data i'm getting this error;

> AttributeError: module 'scipy.ndimage' has no attribute 'interpolation'

This is the list of all imported libraries;

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import scipy.ndimage
import numpy
import random
import pathlib
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import zipfile
import wget
```

```py
# Create an augmented data generator
train_datagen_augmented = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.,
                                             rotation_range=0.2,
                                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                                             height_shift_range=0.2,
                                             zoom_range=0.2,
                                             horizontal_flip=True)

train_data_augmented = train_datagen_augmented.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                                  target_size=(224, 224),
                                                                  batch_size=32,
                                                                  class_mode='categorical')


# Clone the model (use the same architecture)
model_3 = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model)

# Compile the cloned model (same setup as used for model)
model_3.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=["accuracy"])

# Fit the model
history_3 = model_3.fit(train_data_augmented, # use augmented data
                          epochs=5,
                          steps_per_epoch=len(train_data_augmented),
                          validation_data=test_data,
                          validation_steps=len(test_data))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 6, in 
> history_3 = model_3.fit(train_data_augmented, # use augmented data
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
> line 1133, in fit
> data_handler = data_adapter.get_data_handler(
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py",
> line 1364, in get_data_handler
> return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py",
> line 1154, in **init**
> self._adapter = adapter_cls(
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py",
> line 932, in **init**
> super(KerasSequenceAdapter, self).**init**(
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py",
> line 809, in **init**
> peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py",
> line 943, in _peek_and_restore
> return x[0], x
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py",
> line 65, in **getitem**
> return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py",
> line 238, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
> x = self.image_data_generator.apply_transform(x, params)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py",
> line 863, in apply_transform
> x = apply_affine_transform(x, transform_parameters.get('theta', 0),
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\affine_transformations.py",
> line 327, in apply_affine_transform
> channel_images = [ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform(
>
> File
> "C:\Users\batuh\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\affine_transformations.py",
> line 327, in 
> channel_images = [ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform(
>
> AttributeError: module 'scipy.ndimage' has no attribute
> 'interpolation'

Comment: pls add complete error traceback in your question. That will help to understand the call chain. Thanks

Comment: @simpleApp I added them

Comment: I think it's related to the version of scipy you are using. i could not recreate the error on tf - 2.3.1 and scipy- '1.5.0'. you can get the version by `scipy.__version__`  and `tf.__version__`. pls add your versions to the question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Problem was that `scipy` was missing in my anaconda virtual environment. I thought `scipy` was installed when I saw;

> AttributeError: module 'scipy.ndimage' has no attribute
> 'interpolation'

Thanks for the tip @simpleApp. And I'm sorry to bother you with the mistake of absent-mindedness... Solution is the installing `scipy`.